# URL with login parameter

Tags: ios, json, post

I have been scratching my head on this one for some time. Assuming I have a url like so

//myurl/index.jsp?user_name=bob&user_pwd=new

and a login form on my app with username and password texfields and a login button. When the user enters "bob" as username and "new" as password, I would like to push to another viewcontroller.

I know how to do this using standard hard coded ways but i would like to try via post to a url/webservice.

How do you go about doing this?

Comment: use libraries like AFNetworking?

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
NSString *url = @"http://myurl/index.jsp?"; //your url
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_name=%@&user_pwd=%@",UserName,Password] ;
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]; 
[request setTimeoutInterval:20]; //time out interval 
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSError *error;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *data=[[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
NSLog(@"Login response %@ :",data);
[request release];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use AFNetworking Library.  You run the request with blocks so you can run a success block that if the login is successful, you can push a new view controller and if it fails you can throw a UIAlert or something else.  You will just want to take the username and password text from the UITextFields and put that in your URL request.

More info on AFNetworking below.  Also way faster than standard NSHTTP requests.

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)